# how can find the corresponding list?

Tags: lambda, racket

```
(define-struct course (subject number title))
;; A Course is a (make-course Sym Nat Str)
;; where: ;; subject is the subject of the course
;; number is the course number of the course
;; title is the of the course

(define-struct student (id name age courses))
;; A Student is a (make-student Nat Str Nat (listof Course))
;; where: ;; id is the student id for the student
;; name is the name of the student
;; age is the age of the student
;; courses is a list, with one element for each different course
;; the students are enrolled in 

(define math135 (make-course 'MATH 135 "Algebra"))
(define chem101 (make-course 'CHEM 101 "Intro to chemistry"))
(define eco638  (make-course 'ECO 638 "Econ"))
(define arts392 (make-course 'ARTS 392 "Arts"))
(define cs101 (make-course 'CS 101 "Intro to CS"))

(define stu1 (make-student 373647 "Mary" 40 (list math135 eco638)))
(define stu2 (make-student 367339 "Tony" 21 (list chem101 cs101 math135)))
(define stu3 (make-student 362927 "Joy"  35 (list chem101 arts392)))

(define students (list stu1 stu2 stu3))
```

So far, I've found the corresponding course, like this:

```
(filter (lambda (lst)
          (and (symbol? coursesub (course-subject lst))
               (equal? coursenum (course-number lst)))) los)
```

Then what should i do in order to produce the corresponding student list?
for example,

```
(check-expect (students-in-course 'MATH 135 students) (list stu1 stu2))
```

Comment: I think in stackoverflow already have similar question (search struct).

Answer (score 0):

Filter those students whose courses list has a course that matches `cname`, `cnum`.

```
; Symbol Number [List-of Student] -> [List-of Student]
(define (students-in-course.v2 coursesub coursenum lst)
  (local ((define (course-match? course)
            (and (symbol=? (course-subject course) coursesub)
                 (= (course-number course) coursenum))))
    (filter (λ (student) (ormap course-match? (student-courses student))) lst)))
```

edit: **Version 2** (no local):

```
; Symbol Number Course -> Boolean
(define (course-match? coursesub coursenum course)
  (and (symbol=? (course-subject course) coursesub)
       (= (course-number course) coursenum)))

; Symbol Number [List-of Student] -> [List-of Student]
(define (students-in-course.v2 coursesub coursenum lst)
  (filter (λ (student) (ormap (λ (course) (course-match? coursesub coursenum course))
                              (student-courses student)))
          lst))
```

edit: **Version 3** (no helper):

```
; Symbol Number [List-of Student] -> [List-of Student]
(define (students-in-course.v2 coursesub coursenum lst)
  (filter (λ (student)
            (ormap (λ (course)
                     (and (symbol=? (course-subject course) coursesub)
                          (= (course-number course) coursenum)))
                   (student-courses student)))
          lst))
```

Comment: thx! but if we are not allowed to use local nor explicit recursion, then what should we do?

Comment: For the former, see edit. I'm not sure what you mean by "explicit recursion", there are no recursive calls.

Comment: sorry about my unclear explanation. actually, for this question, named helper function is not allowed at the same time, that is, we can only use lambda and abstract list functions. i just don't know after I identify the corresponding course list (what you do in course-match?), what should i do in the next step. thx for your patience!

Comment: Replacing the call to `course-match?` its body should do it. See edit.